# What is the best REST API design that enables a resource to be sent by email?

Tags: rest, api-design

I'm designing a REST API for an ordering system using the CRUD paradigm.

My routes are as follows:

```
 - GET    orders
 - POST   orders
 - GET    orders/{order}
 - PATCH  orders/{order}
 - DELETE orders/{order}
```

This makes perfect sense to me, however, each order can then be sent by email once it has been reviewed and I'm not 100% sure what way to approach it.

I had thought of using:

```
 - POST orders/{order}/sendemail
```

but then I think I'm using POST incorrectly because it's used for creating resources. Also the route now has a verb in it, which isn't ideal for a resource based REST API.

Then my next thought was to use:

```
- POST emails/orders/{order}
```

but that would then imply that emails are a resource which they aren't.

Or should I be using a combination of routes and query strings?

```
POST orders/{orders}?send-email=true
```

What would be the best way?

Comment: What is the sematics of sending this email? Some sort of confimation for the client? Who does trigger this process? The client or the store? Do you have different emails or only one?I'd do something like `POST orders/{order}/email` Because technically you are creating some kind of resource (the email) even if it's maybe not stored in your database.

Comment: You could even store some record for the email in your database and provide some endpoint `GET orders/{order}/emails` to receive a list of emails sent for this particular order ...

Comment: @derpirscher The email is confirmation to the client that their order has been created. The store will trigger this by reviewing the order and the approving it. It'll only be the one email. So you would use my first thought but drop the verb. Is that due to not having verbs in the route or just making it shorter?

Comment: @derpirscher your second comment's a good point I'll definitely think about that. Thanks.

Comment: If there is (an will ever be) only the confirmation email, you could probably call the endpoint also `confirmation` instead of `email`. But in the future, you might want to send additional emails (shipping notice, ...) so I think `emails` might be a good fit

Comment: @derpirscher then how would you distinguish between confirmation of order, or delivery etc.?  `POST orders/{order}/emails/confirmation` or `POST orders/{order}/emails/delivery` something like that?

Comment: Either that or just add a POST body with a type (and probably additonal data)

Answer (score 0):

> I think I'm using POST incorrectly because it's used for creating resources. Also the route now has a verb in it, which isn't ideal for a resource based REST API.

Both of those ideas are wrong.  POST doesn't mean create, it means [POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3).  See also [Fielding 2009](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post)

> POST serves many useful purposes in HTTP, including the general purpose of "this action isn’t worth standardizing."

REST doesn't care what spelling conventions you use for your resource identifiers; as an experiment, see if the following links work the way you expect:

- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/get
- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/post
- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/put
- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/patch
- https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/delete

---

Presumably, you don't want to send emails any time a web crawler happens to come by, indexing your resources, or when a smart cache tries to optimistically load all the links that it knows about, so you are going to want to consider [unsafe](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1) methods.

POST is the most straight forward choice

```
POST /??? HTTP/2.0
Content-Type: text/plain

Hey Bob,

Please send the email for order #12345
```

Riddle: if all of the information that you need is in the body of the HTTP request, does it matter what the target-uri in the request-line is?

Answer: yes!  It matters because *caching*; the target-uri for the request also identifies that document that should be [invalidated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) in the cache if the request is successful.

In other words, we want to look for some related resource (document) whose representations will be changed if the request is successful.  In this specific case, that might be a document that somewhere in its representation includes the status of the email itself.

The most obvious candidate?  The resource for the order itself

```
POST /orders/12345 HTTP/2.0
Content-Type: text/plain

Hey Bob,

Please send the email for order #12345
```

---

You can also use a remote authoring idiom; the basic idea being that the client edits the document, and then the server figures out what to do based on the edits.  For example

```
GET /???
```

```
200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain

Order #12345
Email:
  Status: PENDING APPROVAL
```

```
PUT /???

Order #12345
Email:
  Status: APPROVED
```

And then its up to the server to diff the two different representations of the resource, and figure out that the status changed and therefore the email should be sent.

Again, you've got some freedom about what `/???` should be - is it the *same* document as the order itself? is it some other document?  is that other document in a subordinate location to the order document, or in some other part of the hierarchy?

Neither REST nor HTTP cares very much, other than noting that if the resource identifiers are different, then they are different documents with independent caching policies.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are trying to think of how you request an email in REST terms as a resource, but you said yourself that emails aren't a resource. It sounds like emails are an indirect *result* of some sort of state change (the review and approval of an order).

Maybe it makes sense to have order approvals as a resource. If the email generation is tied to the approval process you can have;
`/approvals/orders/{order}`
With a POST operation to create an approval for the order. This would trigger the email.

Alternatively, if the status is tied into the order you might have;
`/orders/{order}`
with a PUT operation to update a status field from `pending` to `approved` and this would trigger the email.